# Data's order is not correct in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is my DB data's sample:

both two columns are **int**

```
 tuanId ,tuanSort
'375579', '55'
'370576', '54'
'366222', '54'
 ...
'346268', '52'
'369608', '52'
'370587', '52'
'370775', '52'
 ...
'370225', '52'
'370588', '52'
'360758', '52'
'366390', '51'
```

and I try these sqls bellow:

```
SELECT * FROM `tuan`.`TuanItem` WHERE ... ORDER BY `tuanSort` DESC LIMIT 140,20;


SELECT * FROM `tuan`.`TuanItem` WHERE ... ORDER BY `tuanSort` DESC LIMIT 160,20;
```

and I get these wrong data, I want to make a pagination, but the second page has some same data in the first page:

**For Example, the first pic's 17th row has shown twice in the 2 pics**

> [image]
>   [image]

So, is the sort value the same can cause such a problem? Or MySQL has problem with such a select?

Comment: Is `tuanSort` a char/varchar column?

Comment: Can you explain what's the problem is? I can not see it.

Comment: How many rows in your table? Why are you using such an offset?

Comment: @Jens: I think the problem is that there are eight rows that have a value of `'53'` for `tuanSort`. In one query, seven of those rows are returned. In the next query, one of those rows is returned. But there is no guarantee that the one `tuanSort='53'` row returned in the second query will not be a row that was returned by the first query, because the `ORDER BY` clause only specifies the resultset be ordered by the one non-unique column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `tuanSort` is not unique, the behavior is within the specification.

You are observing that one query returns a particular row as 157th row. In another query execution, it's returned as the 161st row.

To get more deterministic sequence, specify additional columns in the ORDER BY clause, e.g.

```
ORDER BY tuanSort DESC, tuanId DESC
```

---

If the intent behind this sequence of statements is "paging", there are more efficient approaches, such as saving a unique, sequenced identifier from the "last" row of the previous page.

If `tuanSort,tuanId` tuple is unique...

```
WHERE tuanSort <= :last_tuanSort
  AND ( tuanSort < :last_tuanSort OR tuanId < :last_tuanId )
  AND ... 
ORDER BY tuanSort DESC, tuanId DESC
LIMIT 20
```

If you fetch all twenty rows, save `tuanSort` and `tuanId` from that last row. On the next "page", supply those saved values in the query predicates.

But that's an answer to a question you didn't ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot! and how mysql do the select when the ordering key is not unique? Is the result sorted? If they are sorted, why the two select has a repeat row?

Comment: @MikeTang: the rows are guaranteed to be "in order" only by the expressions specified in the ORDER BY clause. If the combination of columns in the ORDER BY clause is not unique, then MySQL can return the rows within the set of matching values in any order it chooses... there's no guarantee what order those rows will be returned in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to refresh your database table.

Try this : Go ->TuanItem->Click Operations->Alter table order by-> select your tuanid and set as an ascending order.

Comment: Perform these actions in the mysql (phpmyadmin).

Comment: Yes, I try the tuanId as the ascending order.But what is the reason? When ordering has the same value, MySQL does not sort the result?

Comment: While this may influence the observed resultset, this does not guarantee the order that rows will be returned in by any particular query. To have a resultset returned in a particular sequence, we need to use appropriate expressions in an `ORDER BY` clause on the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, your getting same data in 2 query.

then change the `limit 160,20` to

```
SELECT * FROM `tuan`.`TuanItem` WHERE ... ORDER BY `tuanSort` DESC LIMIT 140,0;

SELECT * FROM `tuan`.`TuanItem` WHERE ... ORDER BY `tuanSort` DESC LIMIT 160,141;
```

the 0 is the offset which means the data start at 0 and the second query start at the 141 so that you cannot get same value twice

Comment: I don't think that's the problem at all. In MySQL **`LIMIT m,n`** says "skip the first **`m`** rows and return the next **`n`** rows.

Comment: no m is the limit of the result and n is the first return of the result. did you try it

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. I'm going to ask you the same question: did you try it? I think you are confused about the order of the arguments. The order is different when a comma is used rather than the `OFFSET` keyword. That is, `LIMIT m,n` is equivalent to `LIMIT n OFFSET m`.   [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html). "With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return."